# Parameter of type img

Tags: jquery, parameter-passing, image

I have a main image that moves around the screen and also a function `isOverlap` that checks to see if two images are overlapped at all. At the moment, I have to individually call the method with varying parameters dependent on the class of the other object, for example `isOverlap("#mainObj", ".secondObject);`.

I am wondering, is there a way to pass a generic input of type `img` (regardless of class) to the function? Like `isOverlap("#mainObj", "<img>");`?

***EDIT*** Here is jsFiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/Zeaklous/zpThx/1/

Comment: Depends on how your function is implemented. Try `isOverlap("#mainObj", "img");`

Comment: My implementation is `function moveMario() { if(isOverlap(mObj, "img")){tempp=true;}}` I had already tried plain `"img"`; guessing my implementation is incorrect for it?

Comment: Yes, I meant the code inside `isOverlap` function. `=]`

Comment: I added a jsFiddle in the question. Please look at the implementation

Comment: Yeah as Armin said you need iteration. I didn't test it but this should give you an idea: http://jsfiddle.net/zpThx/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not using a general selector, which includes all possible images?

```
isOverlap('#mainObj', 'img')
```

Inside of your isOverlap function, you just need to iterate through all found images.

This finds just one object, with the given id:

```
$('#mainObj')
```

And this finds all img-tags:

```
$('img')
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want to use the element selector: http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/

Your example would be:

```
 isOverlap("#mainObj", "img");
```